# Is open source a good option for cryptography libraries?

Tags: tls, authentication, cryptography, opensource

I am trying to find good cryptography library to use with my project. I found open source options like openSSL and many more and also proprietory options like Intel Integrated Performance Primitives cryptography library. Is there any reason why I would chose open source vs closed in case of cryptography?. I see similar posts which suggest that open source is better for cryptography for reasons that more eyes can test the code and make it robust. But how about malicious code that might get in (ex: heartbleed). Is there a tradeoff?

Comment: There are a ton of different opinions on this. There is no definitive answer one way or another.

Comment: If anything, it's easier to get malicious code inserted into closed-source projects: governments pay off companies to insert backdoors all the time, and the public never finds out about it.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Agreed, but still [Citation Needed]

Comment: @WorseDoughnut How about: "According to the Reuters article which revealed the secret $10 million deal between RSA Security and NSA" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_EC_DRBG#Software_and_hardware_which_contained_the_possible_backdoor))

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Yeah, that'll definitely do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Key principle behind open source software is *peer review*. The idea is that many people (experts and amateurs alike) will review the code over time and that review process will lead to better, bug free code. So IMO yes, open sourced crypto algorithms are better than closed sourced algorithms for just this fact. However, both systems are still vulnerable to Zero-days and the like although with open sourced algorithms you are potentially less vulnerable due to the amount of peer review.

Comment: And to extend on this. It just isn't peer review as far a maintaining the code base but building it as well. If one wanted to they could review the code base, build it from source, and put it into production with the peace of mind it is free of blatant backdoors. However as Mike mentioned, the backdoors can sometimes be tricky to spot.

Comment: While it may be an edge case, Heartbleed is a glaring example that peer review is not a guarantee that the code is secure. Peer review takes time, and it's constantly a race against those reviewing the code and program behavior in hopes of finding and exploiting a 0day.

Comment: What if the peer reviewer is a black hat hacker and he finds it first

Comment: What if a whitehat finds it first? The benefits of being *first* are just conjecture whereas the processes of building secure code is a sound practice.

Answer (score 6):

Any answer to this will be pure speculation: there is no right answer.

That said, my opinion is that OpenSSL is at least as good as any closed-source crypto library. Consider that [github lists 175 contributors to the openssl project](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/graphs/contributors), and 1,442 forks, while google scholar finds 17,400 academic papers for "openssl". Go ahead and find me a closed-source crypto library that has received as many man-hours of development, and as much academic scrutiny as that!

The usual argument in favour of closed-source crypto is that while there are almost certainly more bugs and vulnerabilities, you hope that they remain undiscovered. To me, that's not very reassuring.

You also say:

> But how about malicious code that might get in?

I would argue that it's actually easier to get backdoors inserted into closed-source code. Government pays off (or court-orders) a company, backdoored software gets distributed. The only example of this that I know of (because it was exposed) is [RSA Security's Dual EC DRBG scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_EC_DRBG#Software_and_hardware_which_contained_the_possible_backdoor), according to wikipedia:

> According to the Reuters article which revealed the secret $10 million deal between RSA Security and NSA, RSA Security's BSAFE was most important distributor of the [Dual_EC_DRBG] algorithm.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_EC_DRBG#Software_and_hardware_which_contained_the_possible_backdoor)

By contrast, the linux kernel had [one famous backdoor attempt in 2003](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/felten/the-linux-backdoor-attempt-of-2003/) where an attacker stole credentials to the *backup* source control server and submitted a code change hoping that it would fly under the radar and make it into production. This is much more effort that simply paying off a company, and [it was caught within 24 hours](http://pix.cs.olemiss.edu/csci523/backdoor2.html) - with one of my favourite mail-list messages of all time:

> it looks like an attempt to backdoor the kernel, does it not?
>
> ---
>
> It sure does. Note "current->uid = 0", not "current->uid == 0".
> Good eyes, I missed that. This function is sys_wait4() so by passing in
> __WCLONE|__WALL you are root. How nice.

Comment: +1 for distracting me at work with reading all your sources.

Comment: Also interestingly enough, there is a formula for attempting to predict the time it will take volunteers / paid reviewers to find a bug: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software_security#Poisson_process

Comment: @WorseDoughnut Still distracted I see ;-)

Comment: Stuck down the rabbit hole, damn you...